# Installing vcredist x86 from msi Wix

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer

I am attempting to install the dependency of my program **vcredist_x86_2008.exe** and **vcredist_x86_2010.exe** from my msi before it attempts to install the program itself. I have following piece of code.

```
<Binary Id="SetupCA"  SourceFile="..\..\ext_library\SetupCA\SetupCA\bin\Release\SetupCA.CA.dll"/>
<Binary Id="VCREDIST_2008_FILE" SourceFile="..\..\ext_library\vcredist_x86_2008.exe" />
<Binary Id="VCREDIST_2010_FILE" SourceFile="..\..\ext_library\vcredist_x86_2010.exe" />
<CustomAction Id="VCREDIST_2008" BinaryKey="VCREDIST_2008_FILE" ExeCommand="/q:a" Execute="immediate" Return="check" />
<CustomAction Id="VCREDIST_2010" BinaryKey="VCREDIST_2010_FILE" ExeCommand="/q /norestart" Execute="immediate" Return="check" />
<CustomAction Id="WRITEFILETODISK" Execute="immediate" BinaryKey="SetupCA" DllEntry="WriteFileToDisk" />
<CustomAction Id="ResidueRemove" Execute="immediate" BinaryKey="SetupCA" DllEntry="DeleteResidue" />
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="WRITEFILETODISK" Before="InstallFinalize">NOT Installed</Custom>
  <Custom Action="ResidueRemove" After="InstallFinalize">Installed</Custom>
  <Custom Action="VCREDIST_2008" Before="CostInitialize">NOT Installed</Custom>
  <Custom Action="VCREDIST_2010" Before="CostInitialize">NOT Installed</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

I have two other custom actions **WRITEFILETODISK**, which will get the parameters passed to installer and write config in file, and **ResidueRemove** that is to be run on uninstallation, which has to remove leftovers if any. Installing the msi using `/l*v` mode, I get the following:

```
Error 1721. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor. Action: VCREDIST_2008, location: C:\Windows\Installer\MSIA422.tmp, command: /q:a 
    MSI (s) (D8:30) [10:14:20:867]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
    MSI (s) (D8:30) [10:14:20:867]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 1709 
    MSI (s) (D8:30) [10:14:20:867]: Product: LogPointAgent -- Error 1721. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor. Action: VCREDIST_2008, location: C:\Windows\Installer\MSIA422.tmp, command: /q:a
```

Isn't this the proper way of installing another exe from msi? please correct it if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The EXE is a self extracting MSI.  Windows Installer has a mutex that prevents two concurrent MSI transactions therefore it's not possible to have one MSI call the installation of another MSI.   You need to research how to use WiX's Burn bootstrapper to serialize the installation of the two MSIs.

Comment: The current installer is supposed to be installed as `msiexec /i file.msi PROPERTY="VALUE"`. I will get the *VALUE* of that *PROPERTY* and write it in some config file. How am I supposed to do the same if I am to use Wix Burn Boostrapper. Any Idea?

Comment: A component of burn is the "bootstrapper application".  There is a "standard bootstrapper application" or you can write a custom one using native or managed code. BTW, that's a new question and should be posted as such.

Comment: Thanks. First I would give a go at Burn Boostrapper. And Come back at that issue later.